# Android floating layout with buttons

Tags: android

I want to create layout like this on facebook app. Тo appear with effect from bottom to top.

I don't know where to find example (xml and code) for this

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you're talking about, I believe you could mess with gradients in XMLs. Maybe this layout can help you get started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
android:startColor="#555"
android:endColor="#222"
android:angle="90" />

</shape>
```

If this layout is "gradient.xml", you set the android:background tag on your main screen layout to that layout (android:background="@layout/gradient"/>).

However, I may ask: **why would want to mimic the appearance of another OS? It will only create an "alien" app**. Unless your app is fully skinned, of course.

---

OK, this is something you could try to create a floating menu at the bottom. This is what I did, there may be better solutions around.

1- Use RelativeLayout as your main screen layout.

2- At the bottom of the XML, enclose all your buttons inside another layout. I used a tablelayout, but I guess you can use a Linear with vertical orientation. Let's call this layout "bottom_nav". Use this for this bottom_nav layout:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:visibility="gone"
```

3- As you organize your views, DON'T make any reference to bottom_nav. Don't use "layout_below" and above, for example.

Finally, on the button code, you change the visibility using setVisibility(boolean visibility).

Worked wonder here. And very simple to do. If you want to add animations, then you can proceed from here.

Good luck!

Comment: Ahh... and by the way... after this you create a normal screen layout, create a dumb component and set the android:background tag to the layout name above. If it's "gradient.xml", you would do android:background="@layout/gradient"/>, for example.

Comment: David thanks for reply. I want when I click on button, layout like image to appear(from bottom to top) on current activity

Comment: You're lucky :P, because I just finished an app and I used exactly this same thing. I will edit my question. Please take a moment!